# How to temporary block any internet communications of iPhone?

Tags: ios, internet

Is it possible to press some button and temporary turn iPhone into normal phone, i.e. make it transmit nothing over data channel?

I have such button on Android -- to disable "mobile data". Can I do the same on iOS?

Answer (score 6):

You can turn off all data transfer over the mobile network by disabling Settings->Cellular->Cellular Data. It still does WiFi then, which you can disable with Settings->Wi-Fi.

Alternatively, you can disable all communications by activating Airplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

Once "Airplane mode" is activated, you can selectively re-enable WiFi and/or BlueTooth.  I keep my iPad in "Airplane mode" with WiFi enabled, so as not to accidentally burn through my limited data plan.